# How to get a special RedirectView injected in a spring controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to get a specially prepared RedirectView instance in my controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = GET)
  public RedirectView myFkt(@Named("myName") RedirectView rv) {
    return rv;
  }
```

my config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.example"})
public class SpringServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class);

    @Bean(name = "myName") @Scope("request")
    public RedirectView myName() {
        RedirectView rv = new RedirectView("/");
        rv.setContextRelative(true);
        return rv;
    }

}
```

In the controller function I'll always get an unconfigured RedirectView instance, not the one I've configured.

Comment: Why not have a custom view resolver handle your special view?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to resolve a `@Named` parameter in a handler method. You could write and register your own, but that's a hassle.

Why don't you just inject it as a member variable?

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Resource("myName")
    private RedirectView rv;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = GET)
    public RedirectView myFkt() {
        return rv;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a @RequestMapping for the redirect and add it to the Controller annotated with @ControllerAdvice which will be used by the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

First change your configuration of the bean to include the `proxyMode` attribute in your `@Scope` annotation. This will make it a scoped proxy, you want to keep the type and as such need class-based proxies (this requires cglib).

```
@Bean(name = "myName") 
@Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) 
public RedirectView myName() {
    RedirectView rv = new RedirectView("/");
    rv.setContextRelative(true);
    return rv;
}
```

After this change you can simply inject the bean into your `@Controller` as you normally would do. Assuming you have a single `RedirectView` configured simply use `@Autowired` to inject the scoped-proxy. (Else use `@Resource` with a name or add a `@Qualifier` annotation).

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private RedirectView rv;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = GET)
    public RedirectView myFkt() {
       return rv;
    }
}
```